# How to reverse long link using short dynamic link with FirebaseDynamicLinks?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a simple function how to receive a short dynamic link:

```
func shorten() {
    let builder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domainURIPrefix: "myprefix")
    builder?.shorten { url, _, error in
         print(url) // ✅ https://joyabc.page.link/zagQctdk4CJ4nSWF6
    }
}
```

But now I try to receive my source long link base on shorten link. Is it possible?

```
let builder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domainURIPrefix: "myprefix")
guard let link = builder?.url else {
    return
}
print(link) // ❌ https://joyabc.page.link/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fjoyabc%2Epage%2Elink%2FzagQctdk4CJ4nSWF6
```

But it is not the source link I have create a short link from. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is:

```
let url: URL //your short url
DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().resolveShortLink(link) { url, error in
    // url
}
```

Comment: I think there is a small mistake, the first variable should be named `let link: URL //your short url`